# Post form values not showing up

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

This is my HTML form

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <strong>Start</strong><br />
  Lng: <input type="text" id="start_lng"><br />
  Lat: <input type="text" id="start_lat"><br />
  <strong>Destination</strong><br />
  Lng: <input type="text" id="dest_lng"><br />
  Lat: <input type="text" id="dest_lat"><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

But when i look at my Request information the only POST values i get is the "csrfmiddlewaretoken" and not any of the start_lng, start_lat and so on.

Comment: Why aren't you using Django forms for this?

Comment: Im new to django, will have to look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTML `<input>` elements do not have `name` attribute and therefore are not considered "successful controls" for submission as defined in the HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.